# I can't connect Nested VT-x

Tags: networking, administration

I couldn't start Hyper-V in the virtual machine. I read on the Internet that it is necessary to include attached information. At the last stage (VBoxManage.exe modifyvm "Server" --nested-hw-virt on), an error pops up:

VBoxManage.exe: error: Could not find a registered machine named 'Server'
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (0x80bb0001), component VirtualBoxWrap, interface IVirtualBox, callee IUnknown
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "FindMachine(Bstr(a->argv[0]).raw(), machine.asOutParam())" at line 633 of file VBoxManageModifyVM.cpp

How can this be fixed? If anything, the name of the machine is exactly "Server"

Such a command didn't work either:
VboxManage registervm "C:\Users\ViSta\VirtualBox VMs\Сервер_\Сервер_.vbox"